# Defijne meaning of statement in C++

Tags: c++

I am working with some C++ code and I am just a novice and I do not understand what this conditional statement means for a true or false result.

This is what I have:

Font contains values related to bitmap font

```
for(j = 0; j < COUNT; j++)   {
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)  {
        Font[j][i] <<= 1;
        if((j != COUNT -1) && (Font[j + 1][i] & 0x80))
            Font[j][i] |= 0x01;
    }
}
```

I understand most of this, the Boolean `&&`, then the `&` is confusing me for relevancy in this use and then the lone `0x80`, I just don't understand how that relates to the `(Font[j + 1][i] & 0x80) 0x80 is 128` decimal...
The font is a `128 x 8 font`, but is that a relationship?
Can someone help me put this together so that I can understand how it is providing the condition?
I also need to know how |= 0x01 affects Font[j][i]. Is that a form of piping?

Comment: logical and operator `&&` and bit-wise and operator `&`. The `0x80` is `1000 0000` in binary.

Comment: This is obviously a manual bitshifting operation, applied to an entire array (with manual carry of the overflow bits). It's possible to explain, in detail, how it works, but you'll find more long-term benefits in spending a little bit of time reading your C++ book, specifically the chapters that explain how `&` and `|`/`|=` operators work. It shouldn't take a long time to learn this, and after which the purpose of this code should become crystal clear. Learning this by yourself is far better than someone just giving the answer on stackoverflow.com, which is not a substitute for a C++ book.

Comment: `Font[j][i] |= 0x01;` is the same as `Font[j][i] = Font[j][i] | 0x01;` explained here: [Bitwise_OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_OR_|).

Comment: Remember, in C++ 0 is false, any other value is true.

Comment: Thanks Sam. 1. I do not have a C++ book and I've never tried or attempted to code in C++. I picked this code snippet up online because it was working for the bit shifter work I needed. Then when I decided to try some modifications, I couldn't find hardly any relevant info specific to how this worked, so that I could make intelligent assertions and avoid hunt and peck, trial and error sequences. Why is there are always a few online that chastise others for asking questions and always say basically, go read the book? or duplicate question... and act like, don't come here for help...

Comment: Thanks Ted.... I've never dealt with bitwise before... I don't do this for a job.... It's hobby stuff and I've never done this kind of coding before.

Comment: Thanks to everyone here for your support. I appreciate your time and explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement generic format is

```
if (conditional_expression) ...
```

The `conditional_expression` is any expression which yields a result. The result zero (`0`) is false, and anything non-zero is true.

If the `conditional_expression` is simple and without any kind of comparison, then it's implicitly compared to zero. For example

```
int my_variable = ...;  // Actual value irrelevant for example

if (my_variable) { ... }
```

The `if` statement above is implicitly equal to

```
if (my_variable != 0) { ... }
```

This implicit comparison to zero is also done for compound conditions, for example

```
if (some_condition && my_variable) { ... }
```

is equal to

```
if (some_condition && my_variable != 0) { ... }
```

---

Now we get back to your code and the condition:

```
if((j != COUNT -1) && (Font[j + 1][i] & 0x80))
```

With the implicit comparison against zero, the above is equal to

```
if((j != COUNT -1) && (Font[j + 1][i] & 0x80) != 0)
```

That is, the right-hand side of the `&&` check is `Font[j + 1][i] & 0x80` is zero or not.

As for the `&` operator itself, it's the [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_AND_&), and in essence can be used to check if a bit is set or not. For your code it checks if the bit corresponding to the value `0x80` (the eight bit) is set.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I now have a better understanding of this.